# Как понять, что вьюха изменилась? какое событие за это отвечает?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Например, есть вьюха

```
<table class="display table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Table Name</th>
                    <th>Field</th>
                    <th>Condition</th>
                    <th>Definition</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody ng-repeat="(tableName, fcd) in reports.FCD">
                <tr ng-repeat="(name, fields) in fcd">
                    <td>{{ tableName }}</td>
                    <td>{{fields.alias}}</td>
                    <td><span ng-repeat="condition in fields.conditions">
                            <span>{{condition.operand}} </span><span>{{condition.value}} </span><span>{{condition.type}} </span>
                    </span></td>
                    <td>
                        <span ng-show="fields.definitions.paymentMethod != null">Payment Methods: </span><span ng-repeat="payment in fields.definitions.paymentMethod">{{payment}} or </span>
                        <span ng-show="fields.definitions.status != null">Status: </span><span
                                ng-repeat="status in fields.definitions.status">{{status}} or </span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

И есть код, который её заполняет:

```
 var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
var parentTr;
app.controller('customersCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $(".report-generator").on("click", ".dynamicTableReportsGenerator tbody tr td", function (e) {
        parentTr = $(this).closest('tr');
        if (!$(this).is('td:first')) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $http({
                url: "/report-generator/getReportById",
                method: "post",
                data: $.param({"id": parentTr.find('input[type="checkbox"]').val()}),
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
            }).success(function (response) {
                $scope.reports = response;
                $scope.$apply('myApp', function() {
                    $(".popup-wrapper").remove();
                    $("<tr class='popup-wrapper'><td style='box-shadow: inset 1px 0px 8px 1px #ccc;'></td></tr>").insertAfter(parentTr);
                    $(".popup-wrapper td").append($("#requestModal").html()); //Я пробовал с apply, но не вышло. 
                }, true);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Нужно проделать необходимые пертурбации с вьюхой, после того, как данные в неё подставятся. 
п.с. Я с ангуларом фигарю второй час) Но касательно этого вопроса ничего не смог нарыть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если данные для view получаете с помощью ajax-запроса, изменения с view можно провести после успешного получения данных(success-function). 
Если данные модели будут изменяться периодически в разных ситуациях(с помощью ajax-запроса, сервиса, наследования и т.д.) можно использовать watch

```
$scope.$watch('myId', function(newValue, oldValue) { ... });
```